# How to add an img element in div

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I try to dynamically create an 'img' element and insert it into an existing div, but failed. Does any one know how to do this with prototype framework?
Below is what I've tried:

Case1: All html is fine.

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="thumbnailFrame" class="thumbnailFrameDiv">
    <img src="image.png" /> 
</div>
```

Case2: No image show up.

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="thumbnailFrame" class="thumbnailFrameDiv"> 
</div>

<!-- JS -->
var eleImg = new Element('img');
$('thumbnailFrame').insert(eleImg, {src:"image.png"});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I note you're using Prototype. You can do that using [`Element#update`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/update/), which will replace all of the contents of the `div` with what you give it:

```
$("thumbnailFrame").update('<img src="image.png"></img>');
```

...or with [`Element#insert`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/insert/), which will *add to* the content:

```
// At the bottom (default)
$("thumbnailFrame").insert('<img src="image.png"></img>');

// At the top
$("thumbnailFrame").insert({top: '<img src="image.png"></img>'});
```

Comment: I know 'update' can work well, but why 'insert' doesn't work?

Comment: @user2416506: Or `insert`, yeah.

Comment: @FDL: Yeah, well, some are mixed (half jQuery, half Prototype). :-)

Comment: I have found the problem which 'insert' has only one argument not two!!
Thanks for you guys anyway. :)

Comment: @SeanTsai: Right, `insert` has only one argument. That can be a string (my first example), in which case that HTML is added at the end (bottom) of the element, or it can be an object with properties like `top`, `bottom`, `before`, and `after`, with the property values being the content to insert at those locations (my second example).